# How to apply LIKE keyword's search using jtextfield's value?

Tags: java, mysql, jtextfield

All I want it search the related names and set value on jtextfeild, like we got in google. (Give name suggestions that you have in database). Here is the code I used but it gets syntax error. Of course it should get it. Because code is wrong.

```
 private void txtLnameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
   {                                     
    try {
        ResultSet rs = JDBC.getData("select lot_name from lot where lot_type='" + company.getSelectedItem().toString() + "' and lot_name like '"+txtLname.getText()+"'% ");
        if (rs.first()) {
        txtLname.setText(rs.getString("lot_name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I really don't know how to set up % with text field's gettext() method. Please help me. Thank you.

**Added error**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2569)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1521)
at Modle.JDBC.getData(JDBC.java:46)
at lottery.LottryRegistration.txtLnameKeyReleased(LottryRegistration.java:736)
at lottery.LottryRegistration.access$1800(LottryRegistration.java:22)
at lottery.LottryRegistration$16.keyReleased(LottryRegistration.java:298)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6466)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Could you place the full error?

Comment: @Bono I added the error to question/

Comment: 1- don't use key listeners on text components, use a DocumentListener or ActionListener; 2- use a PreparedStatement

Comment: 1. Ok. 2. I use MVC pattern. So I insert all JDBC queries in My JDBC class in Model package..

Comment: @MadProgrammer And by the way what is the right query to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Percent on the wrong side of comment sign:

```
ResultSet rs = JDBC.getData("select lot_name from lot where lot_type='" 
     + company.getSelectedItem().toString() 
     + "' and lot_name like '" 
     + txtLname.getText() 
     + "%' ");
```

Comment: Have you tested the script and does it bring anything back, in a query tool.

Comment: I run this query using GUI and nothing is happening?

Comment: Try select top 10 lot_name .........  .  Using like is often not ideal, as it is often the least expensive / poorest performance option.

Comment: Not necessarily, but from a comparison point of view, it is often the slowest.